# PHP - XLSX to CSV adding spaces

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, xlsx

I have problem converting xlsx file to csv - it ads spaces after every symbol.

**xlsx file:**
[image]

**CSV file result:**
[image]

**CODE:**

```
if (file_exists('temp.xlsx')) {                     

require_once('Classes\PHPExcel.php');
$TypeFile="Excel2007";
$FilePath= "temp.xlsx";
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($TypeFile);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
$objExcel = $objReader->load($FilePath);
$objCSV = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objExcel, 'CSV');
$objCSV->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$objCSV->setDelimiter(','); 
$objCSV->setEnclosure('"');    
$objCSV->save('prf.csv');
}
```

How to prevent all these random spaces from appearing?

**EDIT**
[image: inline]

Everything in one line

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Comment: Is this really an OfficeOpenXML xlsx file? This is something I've never encountered before in over 10 years of working with PHPExcel. It sounds like something somewhere isn't using a correct charset.

Comment: temp.xlsx is a result of other CSV file, which is converted with phpexcel

Comment: What do you mean ` a result of other CSV file`? You means it's a csv file with a .xlsx extension? How is it being created?

Comment: No, that was a tab delimited csv file, which was converted to xlsx format using phpexcel. Now I want to convert it to comma delimited csv file

Comment: You've just confused the h*** out of me..... next question, why are you converting tab-separated to xlsx to csv? Why not just convert tsv to csv..... and you don't even need PHPExcel for that

Comment: Second question, what charset (if any) is the tsv using?

Comment: If PHPExcel is putting those spaces in a csv file, then those spaces are already there...... the beauty of Open Source is that you can look at the CSV writer and see for yourself what it's doing

Comment: I'm pretty new with his stuff, how could I convert TSV to CSV? Because actually that is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Use PHP's built-in fgetcsv() function to read the file line by line, and PHP's built-in fputcsv() function to write the file line by line.... using PHPExcel for something like that is like using a sledgehammer to open a pickle jar

Comment: By any chance, maybe you have any link to example?

Comment: `$fi = fopen('myFile.tsv', 'r'); $fo = fopen('myFile.csv', 'w'); while (($data = fgetcsv($fi, 0, "\t")) !== false) { fputcsv($fo, $data); } fclose($fi); fclose($fo);`

Comment: Umm... That tab separated file also have csv extension

Comment: Then set the filenames as appropriate, just don't try using the same filename for reading and for writing

Comment: $fi = fopen('myFile.csv', 'r'); $fo = fopen('myFileTEST.csv', 'w'); while (($data = fgetcsv($fi, 0, "\t")) !== false) { fputcsv($fo, $data); } fclose($fi); fclose($fo); Would work?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see

Comment: @MarkBaker Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: Did I use fwrite() anywhere in the code that I posted?

Comment: All the results are added to one line now. there are like 3000 of them, so it looks awful

Comment: How are you checking these results? Open the file in a text editor and take a look!

Comment: In text editor - they all are in one line. Other thing - they still have space after every symbol. From bad to worse- but with less code

Comment: fputcsv will put a newline character after every line..... but if it's still putting a space after every character, then check your input file, and check the lines in your input file as well...... if you're working on a  mac, then the comment in the PHP docs that says `If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.` might be important

Comment: Not using mac. Input file is causing trouble for sure then, But problem is - i need to use this format.

Comment: So the original has everything on one line? What platform are you using? Windows? *nix?

Comment: I'm using windows. Added "Edit 2" with screenshot of input file opened in notepad

Comment: I have a feeling that your input file is double byte, with the second byte being nulls..... try `array_walk($data, function(&$value) {str_replace("0x00", '', $value);})` before the fputcsv() line

Comment: $fi = fopen('myFile.csv', 'r'); 
$fo = fopen('myFilenew.csv', 'w'); 
while (($data = fgetcsv($fi, 0, "\t")) !== false) { 
array_walk($data, function(&$value) {str_replace("0x00", '', $value);});
fputcsv($fo, $data); 
} 
fclose($fi); 
fclose($fo);

This code gives same result

Comment: My bad.... should be `array_walk($data, function(&$value) {$value = str_replace("0x00", '', $value);})`

Comment: If I'm using this correctly - it means it does not work. Same result.$fi = fopen('myFile.csv', 'r'); 
$fo = fopen('myFilenew.csv', 'w'); 
while (($data = fgetcsv($fi, 0, "\t")) !== false) { 
array_walk($data, function(&$value) {$value = str_replace("0x00", '', $value);});
fputcsv($fo, $data); 
} 
fclose($fi); 
fclose($fo);

Comment: Then I haven't  clue.... your input file is dual-byte for some reason, but as I can't actually see it, then I can't help much more

Comment: Can you advise please, how to check it?

Comment: Look at it as a binary, see what those additional characters are.... I'd assumed they were hex 00 (`"0x00"`) characters, hence the str_replace to remove them; but I could be wrong

Comment: {$value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);} ----------Tried this - got Chinese letters. No clue what is happening.

Comment: If the double-byte character was a space, then you'd see it as a space in Notepad, so trying to replace spaces is pointless..... that's why I'd assumed an "invisible" character like `0x00`..... look at the data at a binary level to see the ASCII value of that character

Comment: Is there any way to check what exact is it?

Comment: array_walk($data, function(&$value) {$value = preg_replace('/[^\P{C}\n]+/u', '', $value);}); -----removed spaces, but all items still inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fi = fopen('myFile.csv', 'r'); 
$fo = fopen('myFilenew.csv', 'w'); 
while (($data = fgetcsv($fi, 0, "\t")) !== false) { 
array_walk($data, function(&$value) {$value = preg_replace('/[^\P{C}\n]+/u', '', $value);});
fputcsv($fo, $data); 
} 
fclose($fi); 
fclose($fo);
```

This solved my problem. Thanks to Mark Baker